# calling Typescript method in MVC5 cshtml file, bundled using webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-2, asp.net-mvc-5

Just starting with webpack, and I'm having trouble combining some MVC features with webpack AND typescript.  See below for my code combinations:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var wbConfigEntries = {
    "jqkendoMain": [
        paths.appjs + "main.ts"
    ]
};

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: wbConfigEntries,
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: paths.dist, 
        publicPath: './',
        filename: outputFile,
        library: "[name]",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
....
```

**main.ts:**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import '../node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.web';
import '../node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import '../node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/css/web/kendo.common.css';

export default class Main {
    private _name = '';

    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    TestFunc() {
        console.log(this._name);
    }
}
```

**_layout.cshtml:**

```
...

    var mn = new jqkendoMain.Main('@WebpackMVC5App.Helpers.WebConfigSettings.RandomWebConfigValue');
    mn.TestFunc();

...
```

I know I'm including several imports that i don't need (yet) in main.ts, but i'm using this as a test case to update some legacy code.  Basically my goal is to be able to compile/bundle all of the typescript, and then pass to the typescript some values from an MVC5 static class.  I'm looking to call some of the bundled functions FROM my .cshtml files, but i'm not seeing how to do that.  I'm getting that jqkendoMain is undefined, or jqkendoMain.Main is undefined or whatever.  Any ideas on what i'm missing?

Above is just samples of the code i'm trying out, you can see the actual code in it's entirety at https://github.com/vishnu4/WebpackMVC5 .

Answer (score 0):

If using the default `tsc` settings, your generated module will be exporting `Main` as `jqkendoMain.default`, but not `jqkendoMain.Main`.

Removing `export default` and instead using just `export class Main` should make your `Main` class accessible as you expect it to be.

Remember to actually include the UMD-library generated by webpack in your cshtml layout.

Comment: thanks, i removed default, but my code in the github project above still does not work.  i get a 'jqkendoMain.Main is not a constructor' error.  I am referencing the libraries in the cshtml.

Comment: I would need to see the generated output to give you more information, then. Would also like your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: my tsconfig.json is located in the github project i mention in my question.  Direct link is : https://github.com/vishnu4/WebpackMVC5/blob/master/WebpackMVC5App/tsconfig.json .  The webpack generated output can be found at: https://gist.github.com/vishnu4/50f50ea64d4bd26b23024a38fe21eaa6 .

Answer (score 0):

```
This works for me !

const path = require('path');

module.exports = 
{
    entry: {
        default: './src/default.js' // or whereever you put your entry(s)
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: 'YourNamespace',
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    }
    // ...
}

// default.js
import { YourClass } from './yourclass'
export { YourClass } 

// yourclass.ts
export class YourClass { constructor() { console.log('hello!'); }   

C:> webpack --watch 

// _Layout.cshtml
<script src='~/dist/default.js'></script>
<script>
     var yourclass = new YourNamespace.YourClass();  // hello!
</script>
```